# Please explain why I failed this review... Reopen audit queue

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

In the reopen audit queue, I [had to review if this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25784561) should be reopened:

> Flutter - Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework
>   'App.framework' was built for iOS Simulator
>
> After several days trying to find a solution to test the Flutter app
>   on iOS device, I finally found this:
>
> Follow the link:
>   https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

It was a test (unknown until I selected an action).

That is it, it is the entire question.  I clicked "Leave closed".  There is no question, no context, no code in the question, no problem description, ...  At best a comment.

If it had been an answer I would have flagged it as well since an answer must be self-contained and not reference an external link that might change or disappear, making the answer unusable.

If any of you have an idea why I failed this test, I would like any help, because I clearly do not understand.  I am ok with reviewing but tests like that are frustrating.

Comment: Ok, so there is no solution and it will remain in the "test" system?  Ok at least I understand that I am not completely off the track :-).

Comment: No, it will not be used as a "known good" audit now that it's closed or now that it has downvotes.

Comment: I think you should have asked the author of the question to improve his question prior to deleting. It is clear that the audience of the question understood it well from the specific error message used as the question title. The bug that prompt the question was introduced with the IOS 13.4 update which means there are a large number of flutter developers experiencing this issue. Since StackOverflow focuses on centralizing answers, leaving the post deleted with simply reopen a new issue.

Comment: @LoïcFonkam OP (any everyone else who can see the question) can still edit the question if they want to.

Comment: No @Tom, the post has been deleted, editing is not possible since the question is locked.

Comment: @LoïcFonkam The post is not locked. OP and everyone with more than 10k reputation, mods and SE staff can still see and edit that question.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I am not the OP neither do I have up to 10k. I can only see it because I provided an answer to the question. But, I can't edit the post.

Comment: @LoïcFonkam I guess you can't _suggest_ an edit. You need 2k reputation to edit a question without a review. Or you still need 10k reputation to edit the question when you're not the OP. I don't know which one it is.

Comment: I am willing to edit the question properly and await a review if it gets undeleted.

Answer (score 12):

The audit system just selects random questions and assumes that "known good" questions has upvotes whereas "known bad" ones have downvotes. The linked question is really bad question but has upvotes (who knows why), so it got selected as being a "known good" question. It's not your fault you failed it, the audit system relies on the community to handle such questions correctly and they/we failed there.